# Can Azure Functions be deployed to a Vnet?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, vnet, app-service-environment

Can Azure Functions be deployed inside a VNet?

If I created an App Service environment in a VNet and then picked that App Service Plan when creating the Function, Would that mean that the Azure Function is deployed inside the VNet and have the same restrictions etc. as defined by the VNet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can host an Azure function on [Azure App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) which provides a fully isolated and dedicated environment for securely running App Service apps or your functions. You will have fine-grained control over inbound and outbound application network traffic. So it could be restricted by network security groups.

> ASEs are isolated to running only a single customer's applications and
>   are always deployed into a virtual network. Customers have
>   fine-grained control over inbound and outbound application network
>   traffic. Applications can establish high-speed secure connections over
>   VPNs to on-premises corporate resources.

[VNet Integration with Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet) is a feature to use Azure Functions to connect to resources in an Azure virtual network. VNet Integration is only for making outbound calls from your app into your VNet.

In this case, you just need to deploy your Azure function in a VNet with ASE instead of VNet integration. Read [Services that can be deployed into a virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-for-azure-services#services-that-can-be-deployed-into-a-virtual-network)

Comment: New to Azure functions, but continuing from this, can we then go on to use that same function (within an Azure VNET) to connect to a VPN Gateway (to another on-prem network)?

Comment: Is VNet integration for Azure Functions safe and secure? If the Funciton App was compromised, could an attacker reach into the VNet and affect Resource there?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can be deployed inside a VNet. I would recommend you to go through the documentation
[`integrate Functions with an Azure virtual network`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)

An Azure Function can be deployed on an App Service Environment. The App Service Environment is deployed on your own VNET which can have access to on-prem resources via ExpressRoute.

Comment: I actually have looked at that link, however the way i understand it in that example is that the Azure Function is sitting outside the VNet and accessing resources inside it. It is also available on public IP Addresses. I want the Azure Function to be inside the VNet and be restricted by the VNet configuration.

Comment: An Azure Function can be deployed on an App Service Environment. The App Service Environment is deployed on your own VNET which can have access to on-prem resources via ExpressRoute.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: Today you can add a Private Endpoint to the Function App, this disables all Public Access